# Is there any way to dynamically delete or disable a JavaScript file?

Tags: jquery, javascript, monkeypatching

Could you please tell me of any way that I can dynamically delete or disable a JavaScript file?

Comment: What would you want to do that for?

Comment: Is your goal to conditionally load or not load the file?

Comment: Only way would be to write over the methods that are loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

To remove:

```
$('script[src="SOURCE_TO_JS_FILE"]').remove();
```

But to load conditionally:

```
if(SOME_CONDITION_TRUE) {
  $.getScript(SOURCE_TO_JS_FILE, function(data, textStatus){
      // something
  });
}
```

Comment: At the point your script runs to delete the script element, it cannot be done yet. If you run it after the element exists, it has already run.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at RequireJS at http://requirejs.org/